# Repeating Wizard/Form in Flutter

Tags: forms, flutter, repeat

I’m trying to create a “wizard” style form in Flutter that repeats multiple times. The idea is that the user can select multiple options from a list, then for each of those options, the wizard will run. Once the last option’s wizard is completed, the user would then be brought back to the main page of the application.

Browsing through Google and StackOverflow I’ve found that some people will use PageView, however, they are using it to create a single form with multiple pages, which doesn’t quite fit for me. I’ve also seen some uses of the Stepper widget, but again this only works for one form with multiple steps, where I need multiple repetitions of the same form, with multiple steps each time.

The image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lt0YS.jpg) should better explain exactly what I'm going for. In the image, the value of "repeat" would be true if there are more options.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reuse the same view/controller. Build a screen and its controller receiving parameters.

Take a look at the docs:

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments